# Difference between a variable and a declared object

Tags: vb.net, oop, object

This might be more of a general question, but I hope this is the right place to ask.  I'm not new to writing code, but somewhat new to VB.net.  My background is not in computer science, so what I do know I know from the few classes I've taken, my own personal interest, and professional needs.

What I'm wondering is what the technical difference is between a variable like a string:

```
Dim myString As String
```

and a variable like a collection which must be instantiated:

```
Dim myCollection As Collection
myCollection = New Collection
```

I realize the latter is an object, but what I'm not sure I understand is why both the former and the latter aren't implemented in the same manner when neither require references outside of Visual Basic?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx basically it comes down to "value type" versus "reference type".  VBA is a different language with its own architecture though, so what applies in .NET may not always apply in VBA.

Comment: ...or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c  - C# but the same principles apply to VB.NET

Comment: Thank you!  This was very helpful and satiated my curiosity.

Comment: `neither require references` not so. String are defined in the System namespace.  It is an auto reference, but remove it and you wont have strings.  A collection comes from the `VisualBasic` (which need not be used in VB, ironically); there are other collections that come from various places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is different for VBA and VB.NET.

Actually, in VB.NET, you *do* need to instantiate a `String`.  For instance, the following code throws and exception in VB.NET:

```
Dim s As String
Dim same As Boolean = s.Equals("")  ' Throws NullReferenceException
```

The reason it throws an exception is because you are trying to call the `Equals` method on using a variable which is not currently referencing (pointing to) any object.  In other words, the `s` variable is currently null (`Nothing` in VB).  To fix it, you'd need to instantiate an object, like this:

```
Dim s As String = ""
Dim same As Boolean = s.Equals("")  ' Works (same = True)
```

However, your question is still valid because you don't need to instantiate *some* types of variables such as `Integer`:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim same As Boolean = i.Equals(0)  ' Works (same = True)
```

The different between the two is that `String` is a *Reference Type* (a `Class`) whereas `Integer` is a *Value Type* (a `Structure`).  You can read more about the difference on the [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx).

In VBA, the difference is similar, a bit more murky.  VBA has a set of core primitive data types which do not require instantiation (like value types in .NET), and everything else is considered an `Object`, which does require instantiation (like reference types in .NET).  Also, VBA allows you create `Structure` types which are treated like primitive types in that you do not instantiate them.

To further complicate things, in VBA, `String` is a primitave data type, but in VB.NET it is a reference type.

Comment: Tim Williams kinda beat you to the punch with his comments, but I had not realized that about the String variable in .net.  I'll have to keep that in mind.